# The image loads me in the emulator but not from the cell phone with the apk - flutter

Tags: flutter

**When loading this image in the android emulator it is displayed but it looks gray on the cell phone. When calling this image in the emulator it loads me without problems but when I generate the apk the image no longer falls on the cell phone, the gray background remains.:**

```js
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class ImageScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String url;

  ImageScreen({
    Key key,
    @required this.url,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: Expanded(
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: '${this.url}',
          // Ajust the image changing the box fit attributte
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          placeholder: (_, __) {
            return Center(
              child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                radius: 15,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you added internet permission in manifest fie

Comment: yes, <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> but the gray screen still appears on my cell phone and in the emulator if it loads the image

Answer (score 0):

This has to two with one of the problems.

1- I think you are using the release file in the physical device but using debug file in the emulator. If this is the case the add android internet permission in this location

```
android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
```

2- In the debug file you can getting some error. For me when I was working on my project. An error happen which is
`Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget`.
But as this error not give me any problem in the debug mode but in the release the screen goes grey. First I have to resolve the error then it works both on android debug and the release mode.

Comment: option one is ready, but option two I don't know if I have any problems when compiling it, do you have any idea to optimize my code?

Comment: the error that appears in the console is ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════════ ═════
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

Comment: yes, This is the error that occur grey screen. find which widget is causing the error and that will  be resolves. mostly it is because you are using positioned widget in the column or row widget.  or other way around in stack.

Comment: How do I solve it? How do I solve it? I have not been able to

Comment: @Giovanny kindly share more code. so, I can walk through it. About where the ImageScreen class is used.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve for that leave the code as follows:

```js
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ImageScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final url;

  ImageScreen({
    Key key,
    @required this.url,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: '${this.url}',
        // Ajust the image changing the box fit attributte
        //fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```